# How do Access Points determine the client's OS?

Tags: router, operating-systems, user-agent

I noticed that my router (Asus RN-N12E_B1) shows the operating system next to the clients that are connected to it.

How does it determine that? Via User Agent?

What other methods does it have at hand to gather information about the device which is connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of doing it and usually the router uses a combination of 1 to 3 of the more simple variants. The router/AP usually doesn't have the CPU horsepower to do something exhaustive here. Just too much work.

Anyway: It is not guaranteed to work. Some devices don't reveal much information, it may be ambiguous and some devices may actually lie about what sort of device they are.

Typical methods are:

1. For Apple devices and many phones/tablets you can tell from the vendor-id in the mac-address. The router simply has a map-table that matches known vendor-Ids to the corresponding OS.
2. Many devices respond in a known way to a Bonjour, PNRP, UPNP or NetBios request. Simply send a few of these probes and analyze the resulting answers. From this you can often determine whether it is Windows (and which version), OSX, Linux, a printer (and which model), multimedia-device, TV, etc.
3. Devices that support SNMP will often report their OS, model, version, etc. in response to a SNMP query. It takes very little effort to request this info from the device.
4. In a number of cases the way a device issues a DHCP request to the router reveals info about the OS.

You mentioned "User Agent". I presume you mean browser user-agent string with that. This is very unlikely as this would require a lot of effort to implement (router must monitor all HTTP traffic for presence of user-agent strings, which takes a lot of effort) and only is usefull for clients that a) have a webbrowser and b) where the user hasn't modified the agent string in something unusual and c) where the user uses a standard browser and not something obscure and d) where the user isn't using "private mode" browsing (which usually doesn't reveal the normal user-agent string).
Lot's of effort for very little reliable information.